# Exponential growth doubling processor speed

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, exponential

According to Wikipedia article on [Exponential growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth)

> E.g. if a slow processor can solve problems of size x in time t, then a processor twice as fast could only solve problems of size x+constant in the same time t.

My question is, how do we calculate the constant value that is added to size x. I have seen many pages describing the [growth](http://algoviz.org/OpenDSA/Books/CS2114/html/AnalCompvsAlg.html#), but nothing around  how to calculate this constant. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the entry says is something like this. Suppose the algorithm is exponential with base *c*, so that for some input of size *x*, the running time is

t ~= c<sup>x</sup>.

Now given a processor twice as fast, with an input just *a* (I'm calling your constant that) larger, the time would again be

t ~= 0.5 c<sup>x + a</sup>.

Dividing the latter by the former, we'd get

1 ~= 0.5 c<sup>a</sup>

or, solving for your constant *a*,

a ~= loc<sub>c</sub>(2).

---

Don't take this stuff too rigorously. The orders of growth terms just mean that the functions are *dominated* by these terms. Hence the approx. signs above.